# setHasDownloadableProducts function not being fired on checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after event

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, event-observer, downloadable

Recently in the development of a Magento site the setHasDownloadableProducts($observer) method has stopped running when the `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after` event is fired.

Unfortunately I can't pinpoint exactly when it stopped but I do know that it was working previously.

I am certain the event is firing thanks to Mage::Log on the dispatchEvent() method; it records the event whenever a user completes the checkout, just as it should.

I'm also confident the event is firing as I have attached a custom method to the same event and that runs great.

Has anyone seen anything like this? I'm not sure where to look really, apart from the obvious (the Mage_Downloadable extension is enabled) because I haven't knowingly made any changes to the code in this area.

**UPDATE:**
So, I found that if I remove my custom method which is attached to the same event, the original runs as it should... Should both attached methods run when the event is fired?

I found something on this site which suggested adding `<depends><Mage_Downloadable/></depends>` to the app/etc/modules XML file but this made no difference, the custom method still seems to override the in built method.

**UPDATE 2:**
Okay, so I've worked round this by simply attaching my custom method to a suitable nearby event, sales_order_save_commit_after. Would still like some insight on why this didn't work in the first case though and if my workaround will have any unintended consequences... Thanks for reading!

**UPDATE 3:**
As requested, here is the config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Extension>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Extension>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <company_extension>
                <class>Company_Extension_Helper</class>
            </company_extension>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <extension>
                <class>Company_Extension_Block</class>
            </extension>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <company_extension>
                <class>Company_Extension_Model</class>
            </company_extension>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <sales_order_save_commit_after>
                        <class>company_extension/observer</class>
                        <method>setHasSpecificProducts</method>
                    </sales_order_save_commit_after>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_commit_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

As mentioned previously, the `sales_order_save_commit_after` event was `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after` but this failed to run as I'm already using it in another module.

The observer code is as follows:

```
<?php

class Company_Extension_Model_Observer
{
    public $SpecificProducts = array(1,2,3);
    /**
     * Set checkout session flag if order has specific product(s)
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $observer
     * @return Company_Extension_Model_Observer
     */
    public function setHasSpecificProducts($observer)
    {
        Mage::log("Called setHasSpecificProducts()", null, 'Company.log', true);
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        if (!$session->getHasSpecificProducts()) {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item */
            foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
                Mage::log("Found order item", null, 'Company.log', true);
                $full_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

                if (in_array($full_item->getId(),$this->SpecificProducts))
                {
                    Mage::log("Specific order item found", null, 'Company.log', true);
                    $session->setHasSpecificProducts(true);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your config.xml and observer code so that we can help you out?